# Elasticsearch [1.5.2] update_by_query doesn't work as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm fairly new to Elasticsearch so apologies if I am missing something elementary. I am trying to update a field within documents in my index.

```
POST test_index/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "label": {
        "query": " checked",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  },
  "script": "ctx._source.status = 'ok'"
}
```

Looks like it's finding the documents, just doesn't update them. Here is the output in marvel

```
{
   "ok": true,
   "took": 7531,
   "total": 230954,
   "updated": 0,
   "indices": [
      {
         "test_index": {}
      }
    ]
}
```

I've installed the plugin at https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery as recommended. Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance -

Comment: Can you post your elasticsearch mapping?

Comment: Have you [enabled dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) as well?

Comment: @AkshayBijawe Sorry not sure what you mean by elasticsearch mapping. Is it the output of GET /test_index/_mappings?

Comment: @Val I had NOT enabled this earlier. Just did and retried but doesn't seem to fix the problem. Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out what was going on. Had to add another line to the .yml to make this work. Here are the changes I added to the configuration file:

```
script.inline: true
script.indexed: true
script.disable_dynamic: false
```

adding the 3rd line makes the difference. thanks for the helpful comments.